# Async call inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contentful

I have following code:

```
$scope.getEntriesBySpace = function(space, entryIds){
        var entriesHolder = [],
            errors = [];

        if(entryIds && entryIds.length > 0){
            angular.forEach(entryIds, function(entryId){
                space.cf_space.getEntry(entryId.trim()).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Could not find entry using access token, Error', error);
                    return error;
                }).then(function(response) {
                    if(response){
                        entriesHolder.push(data);
                    }else{
                        errors.push({"id": entryId, "message": "Entry not found"});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

i call it like that:

```
$scope.getEntriesBySpace(sourceSpace, entries);
```

I want to store every response after each call finished inside the loop and return as array of responses or errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Method **getEntry** returns promise.

For ref see this library: https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.js

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Hacketo: How would i store every response in an array and return at the end of all the calls are finished?

Comment: @elclanrs: I have tried that solution. But it didnt work I need to have all responses at once. So that i can further do processing on them. Kindly help me here I'll be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's two ways of doing this. When you have promises, you also generally page a Promise.all method which is part of the promise implementations. In Angular, you'd do $q.all.

So then you can do something like:

`$q.all(entryIds.map(function(entryId){
  return space.cf_space.getEntry(entryId.trim())
}))
.then(function(entries){
  console.log(entries)
})`

However, it seems like you're using the contentful SDK, where you also have a getEntries method which has [query parameters](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/inclusion/get-all-entries-of-a-space) which allow you to get more than one entry at once in one request. This would be the most desirable thing because it would be much faster.

`space.cf_space.getEntries({'sys.id[in]': entryIds.join(',')})
.then(function(entries){
  console.log(entries)
})`

Comment: @trodigues: kindly help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035199/how-to-set-contentful-js-api-call-ratelimit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lib async for that:
https://github.com/caolan/async

```
$scope.getEntriesBySpace = function(space, entryIds){
    var entriesHolder = [],
        errors = [];

    var fn = function(entryId, callback){
          space.cf_space.getEntry(entryId.trim())
              .catch(function(error) {
                   console.log('Could not find entry using access token, Error', error);
                   /// just get out of here
                  return callback({"message": "Entry not found"});
              }).then(function(response) {
                  if(response){
                      // good response
                      return callback(null, data);
                  }else{
                      // bad response
                      return callback({"id": entryId, "message": "Entry not found"});
                  }
              });
    });

    if(entryIds && entryIds.length > 0){
        async.map(entryIds, fn, function(err, results){
            if(err) {
                // deal with the errors
            }
            // your array
            console.log(results);
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getEntriesBySpace` cannot return an array of the items you want (asyncronicity). It can, however, return a promise that references an array of the desired items. Or, since you want errors too, an object that contains both the good results and the errors.

```
$scope.getEntriesBySpace = function(space, entryIds){

    if(entryIds instanceof Array){
        return Promise.all(entryIds.map(function(entryId){
            return space.cf_space.getEntry(entryId.trim()).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Could not find entry using access token, Error', error);
                throw error;
            });
       })).then(function(responses) {
           var resultAndErrors = {result: [], errors: []};
           responses.forEach(function(response) {
               if (!response) {
                   resultAndErrors.errors.push(({"id": entryId, "message": "Entry not found"});
               }
               else {
                   resultAndErrors.result.push(response);
               }
           });
           return resultAndErrors;
       });
    }
    else {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
};
```